# SharePoint Query String Filter not working with space

Tags: javascript, query-string, filter

I am creating a url that looks like this:

> "http://servername/sites/mywebsite/sitespages/page.aspx?ProcessName=my
>   initial process"

But when I redirect SharePoint to that page using:

```
location.href=   _spPageContextInfo.serverRequestPath + varquerystring;
```

It sends me to the page with the url looking like this:

> `"http://servername/sites/mywebsite/sitespages/page.aspx?ProcessName=my
>   %20initial%20process"`

and my filter doesn't work on query string. any ideas?

Comment: %20 represents a "space" character. Please refer this link - http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: So both the URL you have mentioned are the same.

Comment: There should not be issue if %20 included instead of space. Internally SharePoint will manage it. I have tried it and add value with space also. Yes url encode to space but i get filtered with proper result. Please check once filter webpart configuration with value which has no space.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use decode URI component to remove all characters added in the URL and retrieve query string values

```
JSRequest.EnsureSetup();
var q = JSRequest.QueryString["ProcessName"];
decodeURIComponent(q);
```

Above code will provide you Query String values with Spaces as you have provided for redirection

Below image is screenshot of page containing list view and SharePoint Query String Filter filtering Title column from Query String.

[image: QueryString filtered List View]

Comment: I can't do anything after page is loaded, I am using the filter webpart in sharepoint that reads the page once it's loaded.

Comment: Is it SharePoint Filter WebPart or you have developed custom webpart?

Comment: it's the default sharepoint webpart working on query string

Comment: Then it should work by default.. I have just tried executing same.. I am adding screenshot of my trial in my answer...